# Symfony 2 logs me out between prod and dev environnements

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm having a stange issue with a symfony app I upgraded from 2.0 to 2.3.

I also upgraded fosuserbundle to match my sf2 version.

Before that upgrade, i could log in in dev environnement for example, and if I decided to switch to the prod front controller, I was still logged in.

Since I upgraded, when I switch from dev to prod I'm not authenticated on both environnements.

I can't even log in manually on both, because when I log in on prod it logs me out from dev and in the other way around.

Is it a normal behavior which was added in symfony or fosuserbundle and is there a way to disable that behavior ?
If not, has someone encountered the same problem ?

Thank you for reading and spending some time on this !

Answer (score 1):

It sounds quite strange that in symfony 2.0 the sessions were shared across those two environments. This sounds like a security issue to me. Also I do have a symfony 2.0 installation where the sessions are not shared across different environments.

Sessions are stored/cached in

```
app/cache/dev/sessions
app/cache/prod/sessions
```

where you can easily see that they do not belong to each other.

Comment: Even though if they weren't shared (I might not remember well on that point) I'm absolutely sure that I could be logged in on both environments at the same time, what I can't do now. I would like to be able to do that, and I can't find out why I'm not.

Comment: Well, in this case you have to write your own session handler, which stores the sessions in your desired folder or uses the default PHP session mechanism.

Comment: I will consider that option, but I still would like to understand why was I able to do it before when I'm not anymore. I couldn't find anything about this in sf/fosub documentations, so I'm guessing I might have done something wrong with my configuration.